# Add @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable parsing. after migrating angular to 13

Tags: angular, babeljs, webpack-loader

After migrating angular project to latest version which is angular 13 some dynamic import of module not working while compile the project in production mode however it works while I use `ng serve` but not work while used `ng build` for production mode.
Here is the exact error while I try to build the project in prod mode:

```
./src/app/app-routing.module.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
    SyntaxError: D:\frontapp\src\app\app-routing.module.ts: Support for the experimental syntax 'dynamicImport' isn't currently enabled (38:29):
    
      36 |     {
      37 |         path: 'home',
    > 38 |         loadChildren: () => import('./feature/feature.module').then(m => m.FeatureModule),
         |                             ^
      39 |         canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      40 |         runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange'
      41 |     },
    
    Add @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import (https://git.io/vb4Sv) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable parsing.
        at Parser.raise (D:\frontapp\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:6930:17)
        at Parser.expectPlugin (D:\frontapp\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8328:18)
        at Parser.parseExprAtom (D:\frontapp\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9425:14)
        at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (D:\frontapp\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9165:23)
        at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (D:\frontapp\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9145:21)
        at Parser.parseExprOps (D:\frontapp\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9011:23)
        at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (D:\frontapp\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8984:23)
        at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (D:\frontapp\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8930:21)
        at Parser.parseFunctionBody (D:\frontapp\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10159:24)
        at Parser.parseArrowExpression (D:\frontapp\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10118:10)
```

Note: answer if you know how to solve this error in angular project not in react or vue thank you. Also I did research but did not find any solution for angular project.
I have also add these dependency to my `package.json` but no luck:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution.
It was a version mismatch. I have used nebular in my project and I did migration of my project from angular version 8 to latest which is 13 now. After the project migration I also did version upgrading for nebular too from `6.x` to `8.x.`

During the migration and version upgrading for nebular the `@angular/cdk` version was still on old version which was `8.x` and it was causing build failed. Finally I upgrade the `@angular/cdk` version from `8.x` to `12.x` which is the recommended version for nebular version 8 too.

**NOTE:** *if you use `ng build --prod` for building your project you are likely going to have build failed error there is a high chance but not sure. So, if you are using angular version 13 use `ng build --configuration` to build your project.*